# iPhone simulator on Appcelerator

Tags: iphone, appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile

I am trying to deploy sample KitchenSink app on Titanium iPhone Simulator. I have XCODE 4.2 installed.
Titanium Appcelerator 3.0 installed.I am getting error 
`[ERROR] Invalid --ios-version value '5.0'
Accepted values:`

The `iOS configuration details.
iOS SDK is installed correctly!` is configured correctly.

**EDIT 1**

iOS version 4.3. Titanium SDK 3.0.1.
`tiapp.xml` contains `<min-ios-ver>4.3</min-ios-ver>`

Comment: what is your iOS and titanium sdk version ?

Comment: iOS version 4.3 & 3.0.1.
tiapp.xml contains <min-ios-ver>4.3</min-ios-ver>

Comment: try to update your ios version to 6.1

Comment: I cant update as I am using SnowLeopard. I suppose I need to downgrade to Titanium SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading the Appcelerator has solved the issue.